# Join is not working (JAVA Threads)

Tags: java, multithreading, join

Join is not working. I get a wrong output. Here is the code:

```
package Test;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        ThreadTest t1 = new ThreadTest("1");
        ThreadTest t2 = new ThreadTest("2");

        t1.start();

        try{
            t1.join();
            System.out.println("OK!");
        }catch( Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
            System.out.println("Fail!");
        }

        t2.start();
    }
}


package Test;
public class ThreadTest extends Thread{
    private Thread t;
    private String name;

    ThreadTest (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println("Tread: " + name + " " + i);
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        if(t == null){
            t = new Thread(this, name);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following output:
Hello world!
OK!
Tread: 1 0
Tread: 1 1
Tread: 1 2
Tread: 1 3
Tread: 1 4
Tread: 2 0
Tread: 2 1
Tread: 2 2
Tread: 1 5
Tread: 2 3
Tread: 1 6
Tread: 2 4
Tread: 1 7
Tread: 2 5
Tread: 1 8
Tread: 2 6
Tread: 1 9
Tread: 2 7
Tread: 1 10
Tread: 2 8
Tread: 2 9
Tread: 2 10

This is wrong! Thread 2 should start after thread 1 finished and not in between, because of the join() method.

Comment: In this guide to asking questions, novice programmers accusing the towers of mind, the programmers who create world-class leading software that: "their methods are broken" is the height of hubris.  No, join is working flawlessly, it's your code that is wrong.  http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idp42167136

Comment: Your Thread (ThreadTest) is starting another Thread (t). Your inner Thread (t) won't stop if the outer Thread (ThreadTest) stop. So I think main() waits for ThreadTest to join (which happens immediately) but t is still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not joining on the Thread, but on the object ThreadTest.

The method start is creating a new Thread and start it.

I suggest to add a method like this in `ThreadTest` and call it:

```
public void joinThread(){
    if(t != null){
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What the other answers tell you is that your program creates four Thread instances, but it only uses two of them as threads.  The Thread instance that you join is one of the two that your program never starts.

Part of your confusion is due to the fact that your Thread subclass has a method named `start()`, but that method doesn't do what `Thread.start()` does.

OK, that's all bad, but here's a deeper problem:

Q: What's the point of doing this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(...);
t.start();
t.join();
```

A: There is *no* point in doing that.  The point of using threads---the *entire* point---is that when one thread starts another thread, the first thread can then do *something else* while the new thread is running:

```
Thread t = new Thread(...);
t.start();
doSomethingElse(...)
t.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Thread in this method

```
public void start(){
    if(t == null){
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

It should be like this

```
public class ThreadTest extends Thread{

    ThreadTest (String name){
        super(name);
    }

    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println("Tread: " + getName() + " " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 //t.join (10000) add a value large, so that t1 job is over
try{
        t1.join(10000);
        System.out.println("OK!");
    }catch( Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
        System.out.println("Fail!");
    }
```